# Can you pass a variable name to a function to edit it?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a bunch of model classes like:

```
data class UserModel(
    val id: String,
    var label: String,
    val color: String
)
```

and I want to write a function that allows me to specify a variable to replace and a value to replace it with.

Something like:

```
fun updateSomeValue (key: String, value: String) {
user.key = value /// i.e. if key == "label" then this will be read as user.label = value
}
```

Is this sort of thing even possible? It's for a dialog box so I don't have to write 20 dialog box callbacks to deal with each type of var that can be updated, I want to just specify the var and the value in one function.

Comment: "Is this sort of thing even possible?" -- not really. You could have a `when` that checks each possible `key` value and uses that to update the associated property. I suspect that this does not save you very much.

Comment: This can be done with reflection. It is common in weakly typed languages like JavaScript, but in strongly typed languages, it is highly discouraged. It is an inversion of object-oriented design practices that in most cases makes code more difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Kotlin reflection

```
fun updateSomeValue (key: String, value: String) {
    val f = UserModel::class.java.getDeclaredField(key)
    f.set(instanceOfYourUserModel, value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it's throwing an error on f.set:  Class ... cannot access private  field java.lang.String com.... ////, found the answer, I had to include                 f.isAccessible = true before f.set